# Carousel with modal

Tags: carousel

How can I make carousel in this code? On arrow click I want to change to next photo.

```
const images = document.querySelectorAll(".category__boxes img");
let imgSrc;

images.forEach((img) => {
    img.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
        imgSrc = e.target.src;
        imgModal(imgSrc);
    });
});

let imgModal = (src) => {
    const modal = document.createElement("div");
    modal.setAttribute("class", "modal");

    document.querySelector(".category__bigbox").append(modal);
    
    const newImage = document.createElement("img");
    newImage.setAttribute("src", src);

    const closeBtn = document.createElement("i");
    closeBtn.setAttribute("class", "fas fa-times closeBtn");

    const arrows = document.createElement("i");
    arrows.setAttribute("class", "fa-solid fa-arrow-left arrows");

    const arrows_right = document.createElement("i");
    arrows_right.setAttribute("class", "fa-solid fa-arrow-right arrows_right");
    
    closeBtn.onclick = () => {
        modal.remove();
    };
    modal.append(newImage, closeBtn, arrows, arrows_right);
};
```

```
<div class="category__bigbox" id="gallery">
<div class="category__boxes">
<img class="category__categorybox" src="" alt=""/>
<img class="category__categorybox" src="" alt=""/>
<img class="category__categorybox" src="" alt=""/>
<img class="category__categorybox" src="" alt=""/>
</div>
</div>
```

I created an independent carousel but it doesn't start from zoomed image in modal.